# If specific URL not found - 301 to root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Basically I'm trying to edit my .htaccess file to do the following:
I want to 301 a URL to another URL but ONLY if that URL is not found (404).

Thus the following will not suffice, seeing as it will redirect the URL regardless of whether or not the URL was found.

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage.html http://www.example.com/newpage.html
```

Is this possible to do through .htaccess?

And yes, I know this might be an odd request but I have my reasons for needing this.

Comment: @Epodax
Ahh sorry. I have removed the php tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `mod_rewrite` rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^oldpage\.html http://www.example.com/newpage.html [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: I see. But the thing is, I don't want all 404's to be redirected. I only want to redirect the 404 for the specified URL.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to `301 a URL to another URL`. Permanent redirects cause all sorts of problems which **cannot be reverted**.

> I want to 301...if that URL is not found (404).

Again, that's a really bad idea. Even if your deployment and testing processes are perfect you need to be able to see and respond to the requests coming in.

Use an error document to display a message with a meta redrect after a delay to bounce the user back to the home page.